# Is it possible to pass a WITH clause alias as function argument in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I would like to refactor my query to use a subquery as a function argument.

The original query looks like this and works fine:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('hour', (SELECT timestamp FROM data ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1));
```

I wonder if it's possible to refactor a query to pass an aliased value as an argument instead of the above shown `SELECT` statement.

I tried to come up with something like this without luck:

```sql
WITH ts_query AS (
  SELECT "timestamp" FROM "data" ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC LIMIT 1
) 
SELECT date_trunc('hour', ts_query);
```

As I get the following error:

`ERROR:  column "ts_query" does not exist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
WITH ts_query AS (
      SELECT "timestamp"
      FROM "data"
      ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC
      LIMIT 1
     )
SELECT date_trunc('hour', "timestamp")
FROM ts_query;
```

In other words `ts_query` replaces a *table* not a *column* in the subsequent query.

In a more complicated query, you can use:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', t1."timestamp")
FROM ts_query tq CROSS JOIN
     . . .   -- more query logic here
```

I do this in queries that I want to parameterize, having a CTE (called `params`) that contains the parameters used in the rest of the query.

If you *know* that the CTE has exactly one row, you can use it as a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', (SELECT "timestamp" FROM ts_query) )
```

If the CTE has more than one row, then this will generate a run-time error.

Comment: Oh yeah, it perfectly covers me scenario, thank you!